# Problem with dockerfile base image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerhub, centos

I am trying to run a  dockerfile that has **Centos 6.9** as base image. However, Docker has withdrawn support for [Centos](https://hub.docker.com/_/centos). The dockerfile begins with :

```
FROM centos:6.9 as resultsdbbase # base image
    
    RUN sed -i 's/^mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo && \
        sed -i 's/^#baseurl/baseurl/' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo && \
        sed -i 's/mirror.centos.org/vault.centos.org/' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
```

I am getting this error :

```
ERROR [resultsdbbase 2/4] RUN sed -i 's/^mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo &&    sed -i 's/^#baseurl/baseurl/' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo &&     0.6s

------

 > [resultsdbbase 2/4] RUN sed -i 's/^mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo &&    sed -i 's/^#baseurl/baseurl/' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo &&    sed -i 's/mirror.centos.org/vault.centos.org/' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo:

------

Dockerfile:7

--------------------

   6 |     # The CentOS package index for old releases has been moved...

   7 | >>> RUN sed -i 's/^mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo && \

   8 | >>>    sed -i 's/^#baseurl/baseurl/' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo && \

   9 | >>>    sed -i 's/mirror.centos.org/vault.centos.org/' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo

  10 |     

--------------------

ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c sed -i 's/^mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo &&    sed -i 's/^#baseurl/baseurl/' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo &&    sed -i 's/mirror.centos.org/vault.centos.org/' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo" did not complete successfully: exit code: 139
```

I tried to update the centos version to 8 (latest) but the same problem persists. How to overcome this problem ? I've read that many other dockerfiles in the world are also using CentOS as base image. How are *they* running then ?

One more doubt : i am running this in a Debian Linux VM inside a Windows host. So I think this syntax `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` means that inside the `etc` directory another directory named `yum.repos.d` is being created when I am running the code; and this `yum.repos.d` directory contains a file named `CentOS-Base.repo`. However no such directory or file exists inside the `etc` directory. Please tell me what is happening here.

I am very new to Docker so please consider me an idiot ! Thanks